# Getting permission exception when run docker-compose up with dpage/pgadmin4 image

Tags: postgresql, docker, pgadmin-4

I'm trying to build a ruby rails docker-compose postgreSQL db with pgadmin4, but keep getting permission exception from the container. Even /bin/sh in the container returns the same error.

I'm using Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS

Full log

```
db_1            | 
db_1            | PostgreSQL Database directory appears to contain a database; Skipping initialization
db_1            | 
db_1            | LOG:  database system was shut down at 2020-02-05 07:15:13 UTC
db_1            | LOG:  MultiXact member wraparound protections are now enabled
db_1            | LOG:  autovacuum launcher started
db_1            | LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
pgadmin_1       | [2020-02-05 07:15:17 +0000] [1] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 19.9.0
pgadmin_1       | [2020-02-05 07:15:17 +0000] [1] [INFO] Listening at: http://[::]:80 (1)
pgadmin_1       | [2020-02-05 07:15:17 +0000] [1] [INFO] Using worker: threads
pgadmin_1       | [2020-02-05 07:15:17 +0000] [13] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 13
pgadmin_1       | [2020-02-05 07:15:17 +0000] [13] [ERROR] Exception in worker process
pgadmin_1       | Traceback (most recent call last):
pgadmin_1       |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 583, in spawn_worker
pgadmin_1       |     worker.init_process()
pgadmin_1       |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/gthread.py", line 104, in init_process
pgadmin_1       |     super(ThreadWorker, self).init_process()
pgadmin_1       |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 129, in init_process
pgadmin_1       |     self.load_wsgi()
pgadmin_1       |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 138, in load_wsgi
pgadmin_1       |     self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()
pgadmin_1       |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 67, in wsgi
pgadmin_1       |     self.callable = self.load()
pgadmin_1       |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 52, in load
pgadmin_1       |     return self.load_wsgiapp()
pgadmin_1       |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 41, in load_wsgiapp
pgadmin_1       |     return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
pgadmin_1       |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 350, in import_app
pgadmin_1       |     __import__(module)
pgadmin_1       |   File "/pgadmin4/run_pgadmin.py", line 4, in <module>
pgadmin_1       |     from pgAdmin4 import app
pgadmin_1       |   File "/pgadmin4/pgAdmin4.py", line 109, in <module>
pgadmin_1       |     app = create_app()
pgadmin_1       |   File "/pgadmin4/pgadmin/__init__.py", line 350, in create_app
pgadmin_1       |     paths.init_app(app)
pgadmin_1       |   File "/pgadmin4/pgadmin/utils/paths.py", line 92, in init_app
pgadmin_1       |     'The user does not have permission to read and write to the '
pgadmin_1       | Exception: The user does not have permission to read and write to the specified storage directory.
pgadmin_1       | [2020-02-05 07:15:17 +0000] [13] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 13)
pgadmin_1       | [2020-02-05 07:15:17 +0000] [1] [INFO] Shutting down: Master
pgadmin_1       | [2020-02-05 07:15:17 +0000] [1] [INFO] Reason: Worker failed to boot.
***_pgadmin_1 exited with code 3
```

docker-compose.yml file

```
version: '3'
services:
  db:
    image: postgres:9.5
    volumes:
      - postgres:/var/lib/postgresql/data
  pgadmin:
    image: dpage/pgadmin4
    volumes:
      - pgadmin:/var/lib/pgadmin/storage
    ports:
      - '3030:80'
    environment:
      PGADMIN_DEFAULT_EMAIL: 'admin'
      PGADMIN_DEFAULT_PASSWORD: password
    depends_on:
      - db
volumes:
  postgres:
  pgadmin:
```

(ruby rails services are removed because I don't think it's relevant)

revmoing the volumes in pgadmin container allows me to use /bin/sh in the container, but I can't use any command

Comment: sounds like your pgadmin` container doesn't have read/write permissions to the `./pgadmin` folder?

Comment: @richyen how do I fix that? I'm still kinda new to docker. I'm using linux, does chown or chmod fix the problem? And if so how do I use it?

Comment: I actually don't know for sure--depends on your OS, what the directory tree looks like, which OS user you're using to do `docker-compose up`, etc.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I had the same problem. I could solve it by mounting the volume at a slightly different location:

```
    volumes:
      - pgadmin:/var/lib/pgadmin4/storage
```

Note that in your script it was mounted at `/var/lib/pgadmin/storage`.

Answer (score 2):

I experienced the same issue with the image dpage/pgadmin4:4.18. Dug around a bit, and for whatever reason pgadmin wasn't running in server mode which causes it to use different directories that fail the permission check.

To fix the problem, I added a PGADMIN_CONFIG_SERVER_MODE envionment variable and set it to True. In your case, you'll add another environment variable to docker-compose.yml which reads:

```
PGADMIN_CONFIG_SERVER_MODE: True
```

It is very important that the first letter be capitalized. That line gets converted into Python code (SERVER_MODE = True in config_distro.py for those who are wondering), and it will fail if the 'T' isn't capitalized.

Comment: I have exactly the same issue. When I add this variable i get another error ```ERROR: The Compose file './docker-compose.yml' is invalid because:
services.pgadmin.environment.PGADMIN_CONFIG_SERVER_MODE contains true, which is an invalid type, it should be a string, number, or a null```. Do you have any idea how to fix this? Note, I did capitalize the first letter in the `docker-compose.yml` file.

Comment: @eastclintw00d The pgadmin variable section in my docker-compose.yml file, which is version 2, reads:

`- PGADMIN_CONFIG_SERVER_MODE=True`

From what I know, you get the invalid type error when the line isn't formatted the way docker-compose expects.

Comment: You should put quotes around the value
`PGADMIN_CONFIG_SERVER_MODE: 'True'`

Comment: ist there any source where the exact meaning of "PGADMIN_CONFIG_SERVER_MODE" is documented? Can't find anything as of 2022-07-07

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue. Considering the logs that you posted.
If you read the last lines of the logs you will note that the issue is related to the permission: "Exception: The user does not have permission to read and write to the specified storage directory."

The user in the dpage/pgadmin4 container does not have permission to read and write in the specified directory, in this case the pgadmin folder you mapped to the image volume.

By defaut, the pgadmin image has the user *pgadmin user (UID: 5050) in the pgadmin group (GID: 5050)* and that user cant read and write in the host, your machine. To make it possible yo just have to run the following:

```
`sudo chown -R 5050:5050 <host_directory>`
```

Run the docker compose as it is, then navigate to the folder it has created, make sure you are inside, the one that map to the volume, your case: pgadmin

Once in the folder, from the terminal, do something like this:`sudo chown -R 5050:5050 .`
Now the user has permission to read and write. You run the docker compose again and it will create all the folders and files it needs to do its thing, and the container should be running with no problem.

[check the docs here](https://www.pgadmin.org/docs/pgadmin4/latest/container_deployment.html#mapped-files-and-directories)

Comment: note that when you map you volume: "pgadmin:/var/lib/pgadmin/storage" you don`t have to specify the 'storage', it will be created by default. and inside of it, a folder with the email `PGADMIN_DEFAULT_EMAIL: 'admin'` you specified in the in your docker-compose file. There is the place you will be putting the files you will use for restore the db...

Answer (score -1):

Try removing and recreating the Docker volume,  so

`docker volume ls`

to find the volume name, followed by

`docker volume rm <volume name>`

This will recreate the volume thats likely causing the issue