# HomeLab - PgAdmin Issue - PostgreSQL with Docker

Tags: postgresql, docker, pgadmin, pgadmin-4

I’m running in my homelab postgresql.
Recently I installed PgAdmin with docker container, and I have issues when I try to upload a file.

When I upload a file using the PgAdmin gui it actually upload it to the server but when I try to open this import this uploaded file I get an error “permission denied”.

How can I fix this permission issue?

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution:

> I had the same problem. I could solve it by mounting the volume at a slightly different location:
>
> volumes:
> - pgadmin:/var/lib/pgadmin4/storage Note that in your script it was mounted at /var/lib/pgadmin/storage.

From here
[Getting permission exception when run docker-compose up with dpage/pgadmin4 image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60070878/getting-permission-exception-when-run-docker-compose-up-with-dpage-pgadmin4-imag)